# Global incrementing field that could used in thread groups in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, counter

I have a Test which is running for 30 Thread groups and each thread needs a unique variable which will increment and used when the Test is running.I have used a counter in this case which will be used in the API request body.
Now every time I am using the Test I have to manually go and changed the Starting Value and the Number format in the Counter which is lot of manual work since I am using 30 thread groups

My question is Can I use a global variable which will have a way to get a unique number to each thread group which will be used by each API request

I am a beginner for Jmeter so any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There's unique number per thread using function [${
__threadNum}](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum)

> thread number function simply returns the number of the thread currently being executed

Answer (score 0):

Just parameterize it using [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) like:

[image]

Once done you will be able to [override the above properties values via -J command-line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override) like:

```
jmeter -JstartingValue=100 -JnumberFormat=00000 -n -t test.jmx
```

To make the changes permanent you can add the next lines to [*user.properties* file](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization/):

```
startingValue=100
numberFormat=00000
```

the values which you pass via the command-line will take over the values which are in the *user.properties* file.

You can also provide default values like:

```
${__P(startingValue,1)}
```

so in case if the `startingValue` property is not set the test will use `1` as the default value.